# Using `within` in custom helpers

Tags: iframe, codeceptjs

I'm using [CodeceptJS](https://codecept.io/) and I'm trying to write a [custom helper](https://codecept.io/helpers/) that asserts an text and clicks "OK". This dialog pops up as a iframe modal to consent with cookies.

If I write following steps in my scenario

```js
I.amOnPage('/some-path');
within({frame: '#iframeID'}, () => {
  I.see('Headline text for dialog');
  I.click('OK');
});
// ...
```

...my test seems to work just fine.

But when I make an custom helper out of that and configure it properly so I can use it:

```js
const { Helper } = codeceptjs;

class CookieConsent extends Helper {

  consentWithCookies() {
    const { Puppeteer } = this.helpers;
    within({frame: '#iframeID'}, () => {
      Puppeteer.see('Headline text for dialog');
      Puppeteer.click('OK');
    });
  }

}

module.exports = CookieConsent;
```

...and use it as a step:

```js
I.amOnPage('/some-path');
I.consentWithCookies();
// ...
```

...it doesn't seem to work as the consent dialog doesn't get clicked away as it was when implementing this directly in the scenario. According to some `console.log()` debugging the within callback doesn't get called at all. Console doesn't throw any errors about undefined `within` or anything suspicious.

I suspect that using `within` in a custom helper isn't working or I'm doing something wrong that I can't figure out from the documentation.

This warning at [documentation](https://codecept.io/basics/#within) doesn't really clarify when within is being used incorrectly, and using `await` doesn't help the problem.

> within can cause problems when used incorrectly. If you see a weird behavior of a test try to refactor it to not use within. It is recommended to keep within for simplest cases when possible. Since within returns a Promise, it may be necessary to await the result even when you're not intending to use the return value.

Answer (score 0):

iFrames can be a pain to work without when it comes down to automation. There are a number of factors that can make an iFrame unreachable to a framework such as cross-domain iFrames, commonly used for increased security on the content served.

Now to fix your issue, all you have to do is use `switchTo()` - [Docs](https://codecept.io/helpers/Puppeteer/#switchto) in CodeceptJS which is a function available for all helpers made available. The order should be

```js
I.switchTo('your iframe');
..... some actions here;
I.switchTo(); // You do this so that you get out of the iFrame context when done
```